# I can't install ydata profiling in colab. tried everything i know and the results are the same

Tags: google-colaboratory

so this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
!pip install ydata-profiling
!pip install --upgrade typing-extensions
from typing_extensions import Buffer
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
import numpy as np
```

and it resulted in this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-8e3059647d42> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 get_ipython().system('pip install ydata-profiling')
      4 get_ipython().system('pip install --upgrade typing-extensions')
----> 5 from typing_extensions import Buffer
      6 from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
      7 import numpy as np

ImportError: cannot import name 'Buffer' from 'typing_extensions' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/typing_extensions.py)
```

already tried chat gpt, googling, and asking python forums.
it resulted the same.

where i did wrong and what should i do?